# "No module named rosbag" error

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed guide at http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosbag/html/c++/
I runned the example usage read bag file by Python,

```
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('test.bag')
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages('numbers'):
   print msg.data
bag.close();
```

when i run the code it tells me "ImportError: No module named rosbag"

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/nodes/read_bag.py", line 4, in  import rosbag ImportError: No module named rosbag

please tell me how to fix this!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12307/%22no-module-named-rosbag%22-error/) by [suzuki tarou](https://answers.ros.org/users/1518/suzuki-tarou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you added a dependency on the 'rosbag' package in your package manifest.xml?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-02**:
Also you will need to use roslib.load_manifest to get the module onto your PYTHONPATH There are tutorials on using python in ROS at http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials